How I make the text and the buttons be reset to their original state on javascript
I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make a reset button that actually resets everything. I am just trying to get the text to reset and the buttons to reappear once clicked the reset button is clicked because when the buttons are pressed they disappear.
this is my code:


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<h2>A Robbery in Ye Ol' English!(Great Britian, 1784)</h2>

<p id="demo">Random Rapscalion: I am robbing thee, empty the compartments of thy pantoloons!</p>

<p id=demo1 style='"display.none">Random Rapscalion: I am robbing thee, empty the compartments of thy pantoloons!'</p>

<button id=button1 type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none"

onclick=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Random Rapscalion: How dare thee to refuse my request! You have left me no choice but to force thyself to empty thy pockets by force! Outcome:You were robbed of all of your precious money and materials and now have dozens of wounds."'>I refuse to comply to thy with such an utterly rude request.

<button id= button2 type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("button2").style.display = "none"

onclick=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Random Rapscalion: I shall thank thee for complying with such a request, so I shall let oneself keep half of thy riches. As I understand how much of an inconveinence this interaction has been, I shall let thee continue with thy day as long as thee shall not report this interaction to the local law enforcement. Outcome:You were able to keep half of your precious money and materials and were unharmed Ending:Goodish"'>Oh Great Heavens! As I would assume thee shall use force to get thy wants, which in this case would be my precious riches, so I shall comply with thy request in hope of my life being spared!

<button id=button3 type="button" onclick='document.getElementById("button3").style.display = "none"

onclick=document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You: HAW HAW HAW HAW! Folk like I uses a musket for household defensement! Thy puny shank is unable to commit any harmful actions against folk with muskets. Exit thou street of residence before oneself is force to use said musket. Random Rapscalion: OH GREAT HEAVENS! It has appeared you have outwitted me and thouself appears to be at a disadvantage. I shall comply with thy request to keep my life! Outcome: You kept all of your precious money and materials with no wounds, best ending"'> OH MY GOODNESS GRACIOUS! I shall retreat to my location of residence as it appears thyself has a shank and no projectile weapon. </button>

<button id="button4" type="reset" onclick='document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Random Rapscalion: I am robbing thee, empty the compartments of thy pantoloons!"'> this is a reset button

</body>

</html>



I've tried basically everything I could find on the internet but it all just resulted in the button doing nothing, the code that I have is closest I could get.

Once you change via .innerHTML= "..." you cant "get back" the original text.  One option is to have a reset button / js function that sets the original text in the first place and call that when the page loads.  Another option might be to just reload the whole page.  Another (better) option is to have all the texts in hidden divs and show/hide them rather than change the text.   Your next coding adventure step would be to move all the texts out of the HTML and into javascript, then as an array/object.

"I am just trying to get the text to reset and the buttons to reappear" - Where are you trying to do that?  That button does exactly and only one thing: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Random Rapscalion: I am robbing thee, empty the compartments of thy pantoloons!"  That one thing is working as expected.  Did you just forget to add the other things that you want the button to do?  (As an aside... Now would be a great time to start looking into writing JavaScript functions instead of stuffing everything into onclick attributes.)

To create a reset button that not only resets the text but also makes the buttons reappear, you'll need to ensure that:

The text is reset to its original state.
The buttons are displayed again.

Here's the corrected version of your HTML code with JavaScript to handle the reset functionality:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h2>A Robbery in Ye Ol' English! (Great Britain, 1784)</h2>

  <p id="demo">Random Rapscalion: I am robbing thee, empty the compartments of thy pantoloons!</p>

  <button id="button1" type="button" onclick="handleButtonClick('button1', 'Random Rapscalion: How dare thee to refuse my request! You have left me no choice but to force thyself to empty thy pockets by force! Outcome: You were robbed of all of your precious money and materials and now have dozens of wounds.')">
    I refuse to comply to thy with such an utterly rude request.
</button>

  <button id="button2" type="button" onclick="handleButtonClick('button2', 'Random Rapscalion: I shall thank thee for complying with such a request, so I shall let oneself keep half of thy riches. As I understand how much of an inconvenience this interaction has been, I shall let thee continue with thy day as long as thee shall not report this interaction to the local law enforcement. Outcome: You were able to keep half of your precious money and materials and were unharmed. Ending: Goodish')">
    Oh Great Heavens! As I would assume thee shall use force to get thy wants, which in this case would be my precious riches, so I shall comply with thy request in hope of my life being spared!
</button>

  <button id="button3" type="button" onclick="handleButtonClick('button3', 'You: HAW HAW HAW HAW! Folk like I uses a musket for household defensement! Thy puny shank is unable to commit any harmful actions against folk with muskets. Exit thou street of residence before oneself is force to use said musket. Random Rapscalion: OH GREAT HEAVENS! It has appeared you have outwitted me and thouself appears to be at a disadvantage. I shall comply with thy request to keep my life! Outcome: You kept all of your precious money and materials with no wounds, best ending')">
    OH MY GOODNESS GRACIOUS! I shall retreat to my location of residence as it appears thyself has a shank and no projectile weapon.
</button>

  <button id="resetButton" type="button" onclick="resetAll()">Reset</button>

  <script>
    function handleButtonClick(buttonId, message) {
      document.getElementById(buttonId).style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = message;
    }

    function resetAll() {
      document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'Random Rapscalion: I am robbing thee, empty the compartments of thy pantoloons!';

      // Reset the display style of all buttons to make them visible again
      document.getElementById('button1').style.display = 'inline';
      document.getElementById('button2').style.display = 'inline';
      document.getElementById('button3').style.display = 'inline';
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>



Explanation:

Button Click Handling:

The handleButtonClick function is called when a choice button is clicked. It takes the button's ID and the message to display.
It hides the clicked button and updates the text in the <p> element with ID demo.


Reset Button Functionality:

The resetAll function is called when the reset button is clicked.
It resets the text in the <p> element with ID demo to its original state.
It sets the display style of all buttons back to inline, making them visible again.



This approach ensures that all buttons are displayed and the text is reset correctly when the reset button is clicked.
